# WebAuthn: Can't create public key. Promise is rejected

Tags: javascript, authentication, web, webauthn

I am trying to get WebAuthn set up on our login page. I am to the part where I need to make the public key using `navigator.credentials.create()`. On Chrome, I keep getting the following error: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The operation either timed out or was not allowed. See: https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#sctn-privacy-considerations-client.`

Here is the relevant code:

```
if (isAvailable) {
    // Get challenge from server
    fetch("WebAuthn/WebAuthn.ashx", {
        method: "POST"
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        const publicKeyCredentialCreationOptions = {
            challenge: Uint8Array.from(
                res.data, c => c.charCodeAt(0)),
            rp: {
                id: "localhost",
                name: "Company Name"
            },
            authenticatorSelection: {
                authenticatorAttachment: "platform",
                userVerification: "discouraged"
            },
            pubKeyCredParams: [{alg: -7, type: "public-key"}],
            user: {
                id: Uint8Array.from(
                    "UZSL85T9AFC", c => c.charCodeAt(0)),
                displayName: "User",
                name: document.getElementById("tbUser").value // taken from aspx form
            }
        };

        const credential = navigator.credentials.create({
            publicKey: publicKeyCredentialCreationOptions
        });
    });
}
```

Some additional information that may be useful:

- The server does not yet handle this information, but I don't think that matters since the credentials need to be created before they can be sent
- Currently testing on https://localhost
- This is taking place on the login page before the user is logged in. The idea is to prompt the user once they hit submit

Comment: I am getting the same issue.

The RP ID is correct, I am on https (self signed cert), everything checks out. Just not sure what happened. Same problem on edge browser.

Comment: It can get a response if I enable and add an authenticator in the Chrome Web Tools.

Comment: It also works if I use a mobile phone chrome browser...

Comment: @AaronGong what authenticator did you add and where? Not sure if I need to add a certificate to get this working or what. If you could talk about how you got the response that would be super helpful, thank you!

Comment: Hi, it is a virtual authenticator environment found in Chrome DEV tools. I will add it to the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you can test out using virtual authenticator on Chrome, see image below.

[image]

On windows, you can setup Windows Hello as authenticator and test that later.

**Now some notes for your problem**

1. localhost does not need https
2. the expected origin specified if using only http, can be http://localhost<:port if not 80>
3. Need to check the format sent, is it arraybyte or not

I have managed to get it working... You can try and look at my example code and use them, only 2 files

- Frontend: https://github.com/es-labs/express-template/blob/main/apps/app-sample/public/demo-express/fido.html
- Express Backend (using fido2-lib): https://github.com/es-labs/express-template/blob/main/apps/app-sample/routes/fido.js

I am still cleaning it up to make it to production code (e.g. using JWTs / Sessions when passing info between front and back end.

Comment: This worked for me. I think the problem was that I don't have any physical authentication method on my device (Windows Hello is disabled). Adding the authenticator fixed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my supported public key algorithms list was too narrow to support `platform` authenticator attachment. Now I use this list of algs, and it's working as it should.

```
{"pubKeyCredParams": [
{
  "type": "public-key",
  "alg": -7
},
{
  "type": "public-key",
  "alg": -8
},
{
  "type": "public-key",
  "alg": -36
},
{
  "type": "public-key",
  "alg": -37
},
{
  "type": "public-key",
  "alg": -38
},
{
  "type": "public-key",
  "alg": -39
},
{
  "type": "public-key",
  "alg": -257
},
{
  "type": "public-key",
  "alg": -258
},
{
  "type": "public-key",
  "alg": -259
}]}
```